# How to get count using prepared statment in PHP?

Tags: php, prepared-statement

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","uploads");
if($con)
{
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM products";
    $obj = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    if(is_object($obj))
    {
        $rows = mysqli_fetch_row($obj);
        $totalrows = $rows[0];


    enter code here

    }else{
        echo "not object";
    }

}else
{
    echo "db issue";
}
```

This code is perfectly fine but i want to perform same operation using prepared statment.i have tried but could't get the same result using prepared statment. what i have to do?

Comment: can you show the prepared statement code you tried?

Comment: its not working at all

Answer (score 2):

Check out the following solutions

```
//db configuration
$server   = 'localhost';
$dataBase = 'uploads';
$UserName = 'root';
$Password = '';
```

**PHP MySQLi Prepared Statement**

```
$con = mysqli_connect($server, $userName, $password, $dataBase);
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM products";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $sql);  
if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) { 
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $totalRows);
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);   
    echo $totalRows;
}
```

**PHP MySQLi Object-oriented**

```
$con = new mysqli($server, $userName, $password, $dataBase);
$stmt = $con->query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM products");
if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $stmt->fetch_row()) {
        $totalRows = $row[0];
        echo 'Total number of rows is '.$totalRows;
    }
}
$stmt->close();
```

**PHP MySQLi with Object-oriented Prepared Statement**

```
$con = new mysqli($server, $userName, $password, $dataBase);
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM products");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($totalRows);
$stmt->fetch();
echo 'Total number of rows is '.$totalRows;
$stmt->close();
```

**PHP PDO with Prepared Statement**

```
try {
    $con =  new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$dataBase;", $userName, $password);
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM products"); 
    $stmt->execute(); 
    $totalRows = $stmt->fetchColumn();

    echo 'Total number of rows is '.$totalRows;

} catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
```

Comment: not understandable i want PHP Procedural. like this. $obj = mysqli_prepare($con,$sql); mysqli_stmt_execute($obj);

Comment: I have found the solution here it is

Comment: <?php 
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","uploads");
if($con)
{
 $sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM products";
 $obj = mysqli_prepare($con,$sql);
 if(is_object($obj))
 {
  //$rows = mysqli_fetch_row($obj);
  //$totalrows = $rows[0];
  mysqli_stmt_execute($obj);
  mysqli_stmt_bind_result($obj,$totaldata);
  mysqli_stmt_fetch($obj);
  echo "Result is".$totaldata;
  $rpp = 4;
  $lastpage = ceil($totalrows/$rpp);  

  if($lastpage < 1)
  {
   $lastpage = 1;
  }
  
  mysqli_close($con);

 }else{
  echo "not object";
 }

}else
{
 echo "db issue";
}

Comment: You can fetch using **mysqli_stmt_fetch($obj)**, here is the code

    <?php
    $server   = 'localhost';
    $dataBase = 'uploads';
    $UserName = 'root';
    $Password = '';
    $con = mysqli_connect($server, $userName, $password, $dataBase);
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM products";
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $sql);  
    if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) { 
     mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $totalRows);
     mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);   
     echo $totalRows;
    }  
    ?>

Comment: prepared statement without bound variables makes no sense